# What's the difference between Xcode's move to trash and remove reference?

Tags: xcode, filesystems, xcodeproj

When I want to delete file in Xcode. Between "move to trash" and "remove reference" which one should I choose?

I always choose **move to trash** before cause I thought it will definitely delete the real file. But not sure if that's right. So what is the difference between them?

Comment: FWIW remove to trash also removes the reference...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Xcode stores references to the files that make up your project in the project file, namely, the projectName.xcodeproj file. Theoretically your source and resource files that make up your project could be all over your harddisk; of course that's not a good practice.
So, when you add an existing file to your project, Xcode asks whether you want to copy it into your project's folder, which is usually what you should do. So, when you go to delete a file Xcode will ask you whether you only want to remove the *reference* from your project (and keep the file wherever it lives on your drive) or if you want to remove the file as well.

Basically if you check "Copy to project" when adding the file, you should chose "Move to Trash" when deleting, otherwise pick "Remove Reference". This latter option will leave the file in place and just remove the reference to it.

Comment: when I want to add a file to project, what does the option "add to target" mean?

Comment: It means that the file should be part of the selected target. Depending on what kind of file that is, this has different meanings. If it's s source file, then it will be compiled when you build your target. If it's a resource file (image, plist...) then it will be copied into your app's bundle. Most of the times you want to add a new file to your target.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Move to Trash**

This option removes files and folders from your project and the file system. Choose this option when you no longer need the information in the files.

**2. Remove Reference**

This option removes files and folders only from your project. Xcode doesn’t remove them from the file system.

**Reference:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-files-and-folders-in-your-xcode-project#